# Search entire disk including locations excluded from indexing

Tags: windows-7, search

Certain locations are excluded from indexing in windows 7 search, by the look of things using group policies.  As a simple example if I search `c:\` for `datemodified:12/08/2015`, it doesn't find `c:\windows\windowsupdate.log` even though that has changed.

How can I force a search of the entire disk -- I'm specifically looking for changes made by an installer, which are quite likely to be in the excluded locations, which are unhelpfully listed as "ProgramData; Data; AppData; AppData;..." (retyped as it's not copyable, but yes, AppData is there twice).

I'd prefer not to install extra tools though I can I have to.

Comment: I've managed to find it using unix find under cygwin: `find /cygdrive/c -ctime -1`, but I wouldn't call that an answer as it relies on extra software that I happened to have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, with Windows ignoring some locations regardless of settings I used cygwin `find /cygdrive/c -ctime -1`.  With no additional tools the closest I could do was from a command window: `dir c:\users\*.log/s >list.txt` and search the resulting text file for today's date.

Answer (score 2):

Open Folder Options > Click Search Tab > In "What to search" section chose "Always search file names and contents". 
[image: Folder options]

Comment: That doesn't help -- I thought it might as I come across cryptically (w.r.t XP) named options before, but no. I've changed a lot of files in `c:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData` today and none of them show up, neither does `windowsupdate.log`.  I know something of the modified filename but nothing of the contents, so the option as described shouldn't help.  "Include system directories" is of course ticked.